# PHP - Retornar soma de colunas em data especifica // PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Como fazer para que no retorno `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` ele some as colunas *p_line_a* (altura) e *p_line_l* (largura) que se refiram a uma data especifica.

Por exemplo: Uma pessoa que ver a soma dos inteiros dessas duas colunas referente ao dia **2016-09-20**. Como fazer esse script? (**PDO**)

No caso ele deveria retornar a soma de 25,5...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O retorno geral, porem não somado e tbm separado...

```
        $bsc_user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tab_newprodut` WHERE `p_data`=?");
        $bsc_user->execute(array("2016-09-20"));
        $bsc_cont = $bsc_user->rowCount();
        if($bsc_cont > 0){
            while($linha = $bsc_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo $linha['p_line_a'].' '.$linha['p_line_l'].'<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<div class="return_box-list-u">Nenhum registro localizado.</div>';
        }
```

**1-** ele precisa somar total as duas colunas p_line_a, p_line_l que se refiram ao data especificada. 
**2-** como eu faria para imprimir (echo) isso??

Comment: Como esta sua `query` no PDO?

Comment: $bsc_line = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tab_newprodut` WHERE `p_data` = ?");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***SQL*** basicamente seria assim:

```
select (sum(p_line_a) + sum(p_line_l)) soma, p_data from items WHERE p_data = '2016-09-20'
```

***PHP***

```
$bsc_user = $pdo->prepare("select (sum(p_line_a) + sum(p_line_l)) soma, p_data from tab_newprodut WHERE p_data = ?");
$bsc_user->execute(array("2016-09-20"));
$bsc_cont = $bsc_user->rowCount();
if($bsc_cont > 0)
{
    while($linha = $bsc_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
        echo $linha['soma'].'<br>'
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="return_box-list-u">Nenhum registro localizado.</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para retornar a soma de uma coluna você deve usar `SUM` na query, contudo caso você queira incluir outros campos também, você deve agrupá-los através do `GROUP BY`.

#### Exemplo 1

```
SELECT SUM(p_line_l) FROM tab_newprodut WHERE p_data = ?
```

- Aqui eu estou retornando apenas a som da coluna, então não temos `GROUP BY`.

#### Exemplo 2

```
SELECT SUM(p_line_l), p_data FROM tab_newprodut WHERE p_data = ? GROUP BY p_data
```

- Aqui foi necessário agrupar, pois o `SUM` soma vários para fornecer uma única resposta, enquanto o p_data estaria um-por-um, então usando o `GROUP BY` basicamente se esta dizendo que quer a soma das datas iguais.

Comment: 1- ele precisa somar total as duas colunas **p_line_a, p_line_l** que se refiram ao data especificada. 2- como eu faria para imprimir (echo) isso??